# Backpropagation final layer δ term

Tags: neural-networks, backpropagation

I'm trying to understand the calculation for the gradient of the blue weight shown in the NN below.
[image]

In Andrew Ng's Machine Learning coursera module, the δ term for the final layer of the NN is:

[image]

However, in [other sources](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sIX_9n-1UbM&ab_channel=FirstPrinciplesofComputerVision), the δ term for the final layer is:
[image]

where the red box has been added to the formula (the derivative of the sigmoid activation function).

Both sources then multply δ by the activation of the previous node to get the gradient:

[image]

What is the reason for the discrepancy between these two calculations? Could it be because Andrew assumes the activation function of the final layer is g(z) = z?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is that in Andrew Ng's video, the Logistic regression cost function is used.
[image]

Conversely, the other source uses the Squared Error regression cost function.

[image]

The derivation of the delta term using the Logistic regression function is as follows:
[image]